How to integrate functions with floor function ? Please explain me.
How to Integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{[x^{2}+4x+2]}{[x^{2}+3x+1]}dx$$ ?
Where, $[.]$ denotes Greatest Integer Function.
Generally we try to break the function inside $[.]$ in terms of whole square for a quadratic equation.
For e.g. If I tell anyone to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+4x+2]dx$$, then the integral is quiet easy type.
We can say that :
$x^{2}+4x+2=(x^{2}+4x+4)+(-2)$
$\implies x^{2}+4x+2=(x+2)^{2}-2$
Therefore the integral can be written like $$\int_{0}^{1}[(x+2)^{2}-2]dx$$
Now let's substitute $(x+2)=u$.
Then the integral will become
$$\int_{2}^{3}[u^{2}-2]du$$
Which implies the integral will be $$\int_{2}^{3}[u^{2}]du-2\int_{2}^{3}du$$
Now, this is quite easy and anyone can integrate it.
But for the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{[x^{2}+4x+2]}{[x^{2}+3x+1]}dx$$ we have to break $x^{2}+4x+2$ and $x^{2}+3x+1$ separately.
Also the problem is that
For $x^{2}+4x+2$ we can assume $(x+2)=u$. But for $\frac{x^{2}+4x+2}{x^{2}+3x+1}$ we can't assume $(x+2)=u$ or $(x+\frac{3}{2})=u$
Then how to integrate it ? Can anyone tell me about the solution to this integral ?
Please!

I suggest analyzing the values of $x$  where the numerator and the denominator change their values from $2$ to $6$ and from $1$ to $4$ respectively.

traditionally called a step function. The integral becomes the sum of the areas of several rectangles. Draw a very careful graph with the $x$ axis expanded, label the points that Ryszard points out; then draw in the top of each rectangle. On paper. By hand.

perhaps worth a caution, my comment above depends on both numerator and denominator staying positive.  If, for example, the denominator stayed strictly positive but the numerator switched signs, the intgral would be the sum of some of the rectangle areas,  minus the other rectangle areas.....

Use $\verb*\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor*$ for the floor function. It yields $\left\lfloor \cdots \right\rfloor$ instead of $\left[\cdots\right]$

HINT.-Putting  $\space \dfrac {N(x)}{D(x)}=\dfrac{\lfloor x^{2}+4x+2\rfloor}{\lfloor x^{2}+3x+1\rfloor}$ what you have necessarily to do is to calculate first the corresponding change of values. You do have
$$N(x)=\begin{cases}2 \text{ when } 0\le x\lt\sqrt5-2\\3 \text{ when }\sqrt5-2\le x\lt\sqrt6-2\\4\text{ when } \sqrt6-2\le x\lt\sqrt7-2\\5\text{ when } \sqrt7-2\le x\lt\sqrt8-2\\6\text{ when }\sqrt8-2\le x\lt1\end{cases}$$
$$D(x)=\begin{cases}1 \text{ when } 0\le x\lt\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\\2 \text{ when }\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\le x\lt\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2}\\3\text{ when } \dfrac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2}\le x\lt\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2}\\4\text{ when } \dfrac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2}\le x\lt1\end{cases}$$
Try to see where these irrational values ​​come from. Then you have the job of calculating the change of constants. For example, the first addition is (try to understand why before continuing)
$$\int_0^{\dfrac{(-3+\sqrt{10})}2}2dx$$

I have edited the expressions for $N(x)$ and $D(x)$ because they said closed intervals and not floor functions. I am sorry that what an $MSE$ member edited has been deleted and I don't know what it was. Thanks, I know my English is deficient.

@Harish Chandra Rajpoot: Thanks you very much, dear friend, for helping me in English. Best regards.

I think I've found some errors in your answer. In your function $D$, take $x=\frac{-3+\sqrt{12}}{2}$, then $D(x)$ should be $1$ which is inconsistent from your answer.

@l..yesterday: Thanks you . It was a hint and the main thing was the idea to solve the problem. Regards.

I agree with solutions provided above, just that I tried to use a small variation to make the calculations look neater and vitalize manual calculations,
$$\int^1_0{{[x^2+4x+2]}\over{[x^2+3x+1]}}dx$$
$$= \int^1_0{{[x^2+4x+4-2]}\over{[x^2+4x+4-x-2-1]}}dx $$
$$= \int^1_0{{[(x^2+4x+4)-2]}\over{[(x^2+4x+4)-(x+2)-1]}}dx $$
$$ \Rightarrow (x+2)=u \Rightarrow dx=du $$
$$ x=0 \rightarrow u=2, x=1 \rightarrow u=3$$
$$= \int^3_2{{[u^2-2]}\over{[u^2-u-1]}}dx $$
You can also bring out integer out of the Greatest integer function and proceed
$$= \int^3_2{{[u^2]-2}\over{[u^2-u]-1}}dx $$
Now place $u^2=n$ for integers from 4 to 9 and $u^2-u=n$ for integers 2 to 7.
Using a graph from here might be more helpful.
Now make the different cases and solve the area of the graph of given expression.

Earliest answer might have some calculation errors. So, I will fix it and provide more details in this answer.
Let $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}=\frac{\lfloor x^2+4x+2\rfloor}{\lfloor x^2+3x+1\rfloor}$. The idea for the method is to find intervals, say $[a,b]$, such that for all $x\in[a,b],f(x)=c$ for some integers, then we can easily find the area under $f$ at interval $[a,b]$, that is $c\times(b-a)$.
Using that method, we can first apply it into $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ as it is easier. And $g(x)$ takes values in $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$. For $g(x)=2$, $\lfloor x^2+4x\rfloor=0\implies 0\leq x^2+4x<1\implies 0\leq x<\sqrt{5}-2$, so $\int_0^{\sqrt{5}-2}g(x)\,dx=2\times(\sqrt{5}-2)$.   (Finding the remaining intervals is repeatitive and not meaningful to write the process in this answer)
Then, we get $$g(x)=\begin{cases}2 &,x\in[0,\sqrt{5}-2) \\3 &,x\in[\sqrt{5}-2,\sqrt{6}-2) \\4 &,x\in[\sqrt{6}-2,\sqrt{7}-2) \\5 &,x\in[\sqrt{7}-2,\sqrt{8}-2) \\6 &,x\in[\sqrt{8}-2,1] \\\end{cases}\quad h(x)=\begin{cases}1 &,x\in[0,\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}) \\2 &,x\in[\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2},\frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2}) \\3 &,x\in[\frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}{2},\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2})\\4 &,x\in[\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2},1] \end{cases}$$
Now, want to express $f$ as constants:
For $x\in[0,\sqrt{5}-2),f(x)=2/1=2$
For $x\in[\sqrt{5}-2,\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}),f(x)=3/1=3$
Then we can continue until we find all possible $f(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and corresponding interval.
Suppose $f(x)=c_i$ for $x\in[a_i,b_i)$, then we can find the integral which equals to $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i(b_i-a_i)$ where $n$ is the number of possible values of $f$.
Here is a visualization of the method:
Hope it answers your concern!
